# How to work with multiple windows in PyQt5? Passing Values through multiple windows and Calling Modules in Other Modules

Tags: python, class, oop, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a GUI with PyQt5. I have total three windows. first window has one push button (`**btn_OpenSecondWIndow**`) which opens a second window. second window has one push button (`**btn_OpenCalendar**`) which opens third (Calendar) window. user picks a date from there and select a button (`**btn_selecteddate**`) on third window, I want to display that selection in the label (**label_Date**) in the second window.

[Snippet to get the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZKqz.jpg)

Now I'm at this point where the first window works just fine and the second window opens BUT pushbuttons doesn't work.

The button in the second window does nothing when the window is opened from the first one but when the class "SecondWindow" is called by its own and not from the first window, it works.

here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from FirstWindow import Ui_FirstWindow
from SecondWindow import Ui_SecondWindow
from Calendar import Ui_CalendarWindow

class Calendar(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_CalendarWindow):                    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

class FirstWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_FirstWindow):                    
    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstWindow,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)   
        self.btn_OpenSecondWIndow.clicked.connect(self.open_SecondWindow) 

    def open_SecondWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = SecondWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()  
        self.setEnabled(False)
        self.window.setEnabled(True)

class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_SecondWindow):                    
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.btn_OpenCalendar.clicked.connect(self.Open_Calendar)

    def Open_Calendar(self):
        self.window = Calendar()      
        self.window.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        self.window.btn_Selecteddate.clicked.connect(self.PickedDate)

    def PickedDate(self):    
        self.selecteddate = self.window.CalendarBox.selectedDate() 
        self.label_Date.setText(self.selecteddate.toString('MMM')+'-'+self.selecteddate.toString('yyyy'))  
        self.window.hide()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = FirstWindow()    
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Reference Ui Class codes are as below:**

First Window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_FirstWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, FirstWindow):
        FirstWindow.setObjectName("FirstWindow")
        FirstWindow.resize(380, 195)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FirstWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btn_OpenSecondWIndow = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_OpenSecondWIndow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 221, 61))
        self.btn_OpenSecondWIndow.setObjectName("btn_OpenSecondWIndow")
        FirstWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(FirstWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        FirstWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(FirstWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FirstWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, FirstWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        FirstWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("FirstWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_OpenSecondWIndow.setText(_translate("FirstWindow", "Open Second Window"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    FirstWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_FirstWindow()
    ui.setupUi(FirstWindow)
    FirstWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Second WIndow:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, SecondWindow):
        SecondWindow.setObjectName("SecondWindow")
        SecondWindow.resize(654, 242)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_Date = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_Date.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 60, 281, 131))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_Date.setFont(font)
        self.label_Date.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label_Date.setObjectName("label_Date")
        self.btn_OpenCalendar = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_OpenCalendar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 191, 61))
        self.btn_OpenCalendar.setObjectName("btn_OpenCalendar")
        SecondWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(SecondWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        SecondWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(SecondWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SecondWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, SecondWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SecondWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("SecondWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_Date.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Date"))
        self.btn_OpenCalendar.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Open Calendar"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    SecondWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_SecondWindow()
    ui.setupUi(SecondWindow)
    SecondWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Third (Calendar) Window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_CalendarWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, CalendarWindow):
        CalendarWindow.setObjectName("CalendarWindow")
        CalendarWindow.resize(512, 458)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(CalendarWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.CalendarBox = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.CalendarBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 464, 289))
        self.CalendarBox.setObjectName("CalendarBox")
        self.btn_Selecteddate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_Selecteddate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 330, 181, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_Selecteddate.setFont(font)
        self.btn_Selecteddate.setObjectName("btn_Selecteddate")
        CalendarWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(CalendarWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        CalendarWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(CalendarWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(CalendarWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, CalendarWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        CalendarWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("CalendarWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_Selecteddate.setText(_translate("CalendarWindow", "Select"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    CalendarWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_CalendarWindow()
    ui.setupUi(CalendarWindow)
    CalendarWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `FirstWindow.open_SecondWindow` you don't need to create a separate `QMainWindow` object for the second window. `SecondWindow()` already returns a `QMainWindow` object with the proper UI set up and a slot connected to `btn_OpenCalendar` for opening the calendar window. Therefore it is sufficient to do something like:

```
def open_SecondWindow(self):
    self.window = SecondWindow()
    self.window.show()  
    self.setEnabled(False)
    self.window.setEnabled(True)
```